# Guidelines on Github issues + SO post

Tags: discussion, questions

If we find a likely issue in an open-source project and open a Github issue, is it considered good/bad practice to also create a question for the same topic on SO, focused on my circumstances (this is what I see, this is what I tried, please help)?

**Pros:**

- More exposure
- Potentially faster response

**Cons:**

- Duplicate content/effort

Comment: Why would you post bug reports on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Not a bug report on SO per se, but a question like "This is what I'm seeing, this is what I tried, but it doesn't work, please help". Incidentally, I've had a question that turned out be a bug with a framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776253/fb-react-onclick-doesnt-work-when-going-back-from-pushstate

Comment: @Oded - Based on my experience, people often use GitHub issues like a discussion forum, opening issues to ask questions on how to use a framework. It's why I have 1600 issues against my framework, with many of them having been cross-posted to Stack Overflow. I usually close out the GitHub issue and point it to the SO question, if it's a viable SO question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've already posted an issue on GitHub, then you've asked the people who are most likely to be able to help. I wouldn't automatically post a question on Stack Overflow for every issue in hopes of getting a faster response. If the project maintainers don't respond in a reasonable amount of time, then it's probably ok to post on SO (assuming your question would be on-topic).

Comment: What if you are the maintainer and want to post a link to the issue you created?