# At what point do we move from SO to github issue?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256645/guidelines-on-github-issues-so-post) question is kind of related but does not really answer my question.

As an author of a Python library that comes up in a SO question (as the main topic) or in a SO answer (as part of a suggested solution) from time to time, I was wondering at what point we should stop debugging an error OP is facing (in the question's or the answer's comments section) and ask them to create an issue on said library's Github repository.

The main concern is to make sure that SO does not become a "support page/faq" of said library.

I understand that there may be no right or wrong answer here but it is interesting to see if there is some sort of a consensus among the community.

Comment: Actually, SO becoming a form of FAQ for a library is not really a problem: that aligns with the intent of SO.

Comment: Sometimes I appreciate a single nice summarizing answer on SO instead of reading all the discussion of a bug on Github. In that way, Github issues are a "forum" while SO is not.

Comment: TensorFlow, for instance.  If it's posted on GitHub and is not an actual bug, the TensorFlow team closes the issue and directs the OP to SO.

Answer (score 37):

**Step #1:**

Get a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the poster to make sure the problem exists in the way which they describe.

---

Now, step back and pretend you are not the author of said library.

Treat the question as if you have no personal interest in the issue.

As the author, you should have a fairly solid grasp of when to say:

> That's how it works, if you need it to work differently then you will have to modify files x, y, and z.

vs.

> That's a bug in the library, you should report it to the author. In the meantime, here is a quick fix.

---

I'm not sure if this situation is an exact replica of your description but here is how I've handled it before: [Why is array_merge_recursive not recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50948010/2191572)

---

More examples:

[Using CSS3 Variables in Knockout Style Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51368941/2191572) (comment from [zero298](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/691711))

Comment: I'm not sure if you want additional examples to draw from, but here was a question that I encountered with respect to a missing feature in knockout: [Using CSS3 Variables in Knockout Style Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51368941/691711)

Answer (score 7):

I think there is no hard or fast rule that can be established. When answering questions for a library I maintain, I usually discern the following situations:

1. Obvious (to me as maintainer) missing feature of the library.

   Ask the OP to file an improvement request (or do it myself), and suggest a workaround if one exists.

   Depending on the scope this should either be a comment (ask to file an improvement request) or an answer (ask to file an improvement request + provide workaround). Example:

   - [Set default charset on a database created with FBManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715228/set-default-charset-on-a-database-created-with-fbmanager)
2. New bug where the reason is clear to me as the maintainer.

   Similar to 1, I will either ask the OP to create a ticket, or create it myself. If a workaround is possible, provide one. Example:

   - [Java Driver Firebird 2.5 on Mac OS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671891/java-driver-firebird-2-5-on-mac-os-high-sierra)
3. Known bug or limitation.

   Inform the OP of the bug or feature request (link to tracker or FAQ), and provide an explanation and a workaround if available. Example:

   - [java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation exception and LIKE operator relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303382/java-sql-datatruncation-data-truncation-exception-and-like-operator-relation)
4. Not so obvious problems or bugs.

   If I don't understand a question, or the exchange in the comments gets too long (or if I suspect it is going to take too long to identify the problem), I will usually ask the OP to post their question on our mailing list or bug tracker (depending on whether I think something is a question on usage or a bug in the library I prefer one over the other). If possible, I may post a summarizing answer later. Example:

   - [Proper Setup of jaybird/Firebird DataSource with HikariCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911266/proper-setup-of-jaybird-firebird-datasource-with-hikaricp) (not a perfect example of this situation though, but I can't find another one quickly)

Point 4 is the hardest, and it is not easy to say when the point comes when you need to back off and ask people to go to a more suitable venue (mailing list, bug tracker).

I'd say that after asking for clarification 3-4 times and not getting closer to the root, or if you provided an answer to what you thought the problem was and then the response by the OP indicates the problem is nowhere close to what you answered, that might be a good time to take it elsewhere. And as a lost resort: if Stack Overflow suggests that you should move your comments to chat, that should be considered a stern reminder that you have used too many comments to troubleshoot on Stack Overflow.

In other cases, if while reading the question you already get the feeling it is going to take some digging, then immediately suggest to take it elsewhere. If possible, when you have come to a solution, post a summarizing answer.

This doesn't always work though, as sometimes people are not willing to take it elsewhere. In that case, consider just voting something to close as *Too broad*.

Answer (score 0):

Github issues: The author of the library is reading the issue.
Stackoverflow: The author of the library doesn't care about the issue (maybe because it's not an issue or it's too specific), so somebody else could help.

Comment: "Stackoverflow: The author of the library doesn't care about the issue" Why would you think that the author doesn't care?

Comment: Because on Github, the author has control over the issue, he is able to remove, edit and whatnot the request, he has direct control of it.   It's different on StackOverflow, it's who asks who has the control to evaluate if the answer is right or not, even if the answer is right or not, it's not to the author to decide what is the right answer.